# Dealing with integral transforms of Gamma functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, gamma-function

In what follows $\Gamma$ is the Euler gamma function, and the (possibly complex) constants appearing are nice enough so that there are no poles or convergence issues. I am stuck with an integral of the type

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\Gamma(x-s)\Gamma(-x-s)}{\Gamma(x+s)\Gamma(-x+s)} x \mathrm{tanh}(x) \mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation}

How can we deal with this kind of integral? Can I express it in terms of Gamma functions? I am trying to toy with many duplication and product formulas for the gamma function, as well as some known Mellin transforms, but nothing seems to appear because I don't know how to deal with the hyperbolic tangent. Even for a single gamma function or a simple quotient
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\Gamma(a+x)}{\Gamma(b-x)} x  \mathrm{tanh}(x) \mathrm{d}x \qquad \text{or} \qquad \int_0^\infty \Gamma(x+a)  x \mathrm{tanh}(x) \mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance for any direction!

Comment: Can you give some motivation for why you consider these integrals? Why do you expect them to have a "nice" solution for a start?

Comment: @Raskolnikov In fact it is something showing up when working out some explicit Plancherel transform For automorphic forms (I am using Lang’s book SL(2,R))